# How to print multiple excel sheet on client side printer in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have an application in asp.net mvc. In which I need to write data from database to excel sheet which I have store in my project location. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll for perform actions on excel file. And also printing that excel file using dll which is taking default printer on server side.

So if client click print button then also printing start on server side printer not in client side printer because my excel process code is on server side. And I need to mention it there because if client will select multiple chechkbox of records then as per requirement/condition excel sheet change and print data in excel cells according to lots of condition.

So right now when client will select multiple records and click print button then I am placing records in excel file then printing that excel file and cleaning that file and again start this process for record number 2 as per requirement and so on.

So now I need to start printing on client side printer instead of server side printer. I have check on google for this problem but almost they are suggesting to use third party dll or dependency. But if it is possible to print on client side printer without third party dependency then it will be best for us.

So please suggest me that what should I do for perform this task ?

```
public ActionResult Report(List<int> groundIds)
        {
           if (groundIds != null)
            {
                List<GroundWaterSchedulereportModel> gwFormModelLists = new List<GroundWaterSchedulereportModel>();
                GroundWaterModel groundWaterModel = new GroundWaterModel();

                var groundIdsString = string.Join(",", groundIds);
                if(groundIdsString.Length > 0 && groundIdsString.Length < 8000)
                {
                    var list = groundWaterLogic.GroundWaterReport(groundIdsString);
                    var uniqueListVillage = list.Select(q => q.villageName).Distinct();
                    foreach (var itemCode in uniqueListVillage)
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        bool printed = false;
                        bool headerPrint = false;
                        List<GroundWaterSchedulereportModel> gwUniqueVillageWiseList = list.Where(x => x.villageName == itemCode).ToList();
                        foreach (var item1 in gwUniqueVillageWiseList)
                        {
                            if (count <= 7)
                            {
                                IsOpened(excelFilePath);
                                groundWaterModel.OpenExcel();         //open excel file which is store in project's location                       
                                groundWaterModel.AddDataToExcel(item1, count, headerPrint);     //write data into excel file 
                                groundWaterModel.closeExcel();  //close excel file after write data 
                                if (count == 7)
                                {
                                    printed = true;
                                    PrintMyExcelFile();     //Printing start on server side default printer
                                    groundWaterModel.OpenExcel();   //after print it open excel file again
                                    groundWaterModel.ClearExcel();  //it's clearing cells excel file
                                    groundWaterModel.closeExcel();  //close excel file after clear cells
                                    IsOpened(excelFilePath);
                                    count = -1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    printed = false;
                                    headerPrint = false;
                                }
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (printed == false)
                        {
                            PrintMyExcelFile();     //Printing start on server side default printer
                            groundWaterModel.OpenExcel();
                            groundWaterModel.ClearExcel();
                            groundWaterModel.closeExcel();
                            IsOpened(excelFilePath);
                            count = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and here is my function which is print excel file on default printer and it's taking default printer on server side.

```
void PrintMyExcelFile()
        {
            IsOpened(excelFilePath);
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            // Open the Workbook:
            Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
                excelFilePath,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // Get the first worksheet.
            // (Excel uses base 1 indexing, not base 0.)
            Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

            // Print out 1 copy to the default printer:
            ws.PrintOut(
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            // Cleanup:
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ws);

            wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);

            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        }
```

So I need to print excel sheet on client side printer. And main thing is that every time we are writing record in excel file print it and clear it and again we write second record in excel file print it and clear it. 
So how to maintain all this requirement and print on client side printer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't*

*unless you're going to provide the user with a client side app they can install and then you can communicate with so it can use the client side printer, or your server is part of the same massive network (I'm thinking university campus) that the printer is and the printer is shared and contactable by the server then you aren't going to succeed in getting your server to print to your website user's printer

Create the file, send the file to the user as a download, let them print it; it's their problem not yours.

As an aside, you should consider using EPPlus or similar to create your excel file on the server, rather than interop. You could also consider creating a web page table version of whatever data you're currently putting inside the excel, show the page to the user and after it has loaded, use JavaScript to invoke their print process/show their print dialog and they will then print your webpage to their printer

Comment: So if I use EPPlus instead of Interop then will excel required to install on client side machine ?

Comment: If you want the client to print an excel file then excel is required on client machine - it does not matter how you produce the excel file on the server

Comment: I get the feeling you didn't quite understand my answer but..  I recommend EPPlus on the server. It generates excel compatible files without needing excel installed on the server. Do not use interop in a server environment. It is a world of pain. Once you have created an excel file (by any means) and sent it to the client the client WILL NEED EXCEL or excel viewer to open the file and print it. Nothing about the server side operations change that. If you can't be sure the client has excel, do as I recommend I the last paragraph and make it an HTML table instead, so they can print the web page